# Is there any way to to compress large size pdf file using only python library no external .exe

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation, pymupdf, lossless-compression

I have 100mb pdf file of single page with color full text of different font multiple image. Is there a way to compress this pdf to minimum size and then decompress it back to original size with same image and text quality but using only python and python library, no external .exe app like ghostscript.
What logic we need to apply to achieve minimum size compression..

Comment: Suggest to use PyMuPDF. It offers a granular range of compression options: https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/

Comment: Can you provide a example...since I tried it but no satisfied output

Comment: The problem is that the file is itself single page then how to proceed, what can be my first step to compress...how do I provide sample to compress

Comment: Yes you get it right I am working of compression of object of type stream. The info can be gather from this medium article Read this story from ORPALIS Imaging on Medium: https://medium.com/@ORPALIS/lossless-methods-compression-of-streams-and-fonts-c0e694bfc024. Can you help  me to to how to extract this using python, The chatgpt is not giving satisfied output.